# All references in VS C# project could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, csproj

I have an issue with building a project.
The problem is that all of references in a project are with yellow triangle and warn me that "reference could not be found". I tried to delete and create reference, but it didn't help. Framework set to 4.5.2,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do what the error messages are suggesting? Enable nuget restore and check if the .Net Framework is installed?

Comment: @BojanB Allow NuGet to download missing packages and Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio are set to yes, .NET 4.5.2 or later is installed.

Comment: Has that project ever worked on that particular computer. It might be that you don't have the same version of the framework available on that computer...

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried deleting and creating reference again, can you please mention which way you tried.
As you know there are 2 ways.
1.Installing the nuget package.
(or)
2.Having the dll in local folder and adding reference to this particular dll by browsing the dll location.

I have had this similar problem and when I tried the 2nd way above it worked for me.